# Emberjs slider no working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I build a custom carousel in ember and Jquery. Is pretty much straight forward. when click nextImage the slider move the the next image and when clicked previewsImage the slider goes back to the previews image. That part is working perfect. The problem is that when clicked on goToImage(AKA Dots   controllers) the images don't move to the corresponding dots order. Look like my logic may have some problems in the.
   [image]

```
 <nav class="dots">
       <a href="#" class="carousel-bullet "{{action 'goToImage' 1}}></a>
       <a href="#" class="carousel-bullet"{{action 'goToImage' 2}}></a>
       <a href="#" class="carousel-bullet"{{action 'goToImage' 3}}></a>
    </nav>

    App.SliderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
        currentIndex: 0,

        actions: {
            runSlider: function(x){
                 var currentIndex = this.get('currentIndex');
                var indexDiff = this.$().find('.carousel ul li').index();
                var carousel = this.$().find('.carousel ul'),
                    slideWidth = carousel.find('li').width();
                    console.log(indexDiff);
                if(x == 1){
                    carousel.animate({left: - slideWidth }, 200, function () {
                        carousel.find('li:first-child').appendTo(carousel);
                        carousel.css('left', '');
                    });
                }else{
                    carousel.animate({left: + slideWidth}, 200, function () {
                        carousel.find('li:last-child').prependTo(carousel);
                        carousel.css('left', '');
                    });
                }
            }, 
            nextImage: function(){
                this.send('runSlider', 1);
            },
           previewsImage: function(){
                this.send('runSlider',0);
            },
            goToImage: function(newIndex){
                var currentIndex = this.get('currentIndex')
                var indexDiff = newIndex - currentIndex;
                var direction = (newIndex > currentIndex) ? 'nextImage' : 'previewsImage';
                for (var i = 0; i < indexDiff; i++){
                    this.send(direction);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you maintaining your currentIndex properly ? Does it start from 0 or 1? Did you handle the case when indexDiff is negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `indexDiff` may be negative. For example, if new index is 0 and current index is 2. In this case, `for` loop in your code will not work. I guess changing `var indexDiff = newIndex - currentIndex;` to `var indexDiff = Math.abs(newIndex - currentIndex);` will help. If this will not help, I would suggest to put `console.log(x);` in the first line of `runSlider` action to look if it is called and what is passed.

Comment: thank you for that. I never used Math.abs...thank you again